# Reference request: Introductions to current mathematics derived from / related to gauge theories

Tags: gauge-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request

I was searching for introductions to current mathematics related to gauge theories.

Can someone suggest some good references?

E.g.

*[Topics in Physical Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848829388) by K. Marathe*

Comment: Since you are asking for "mathematics related to gauge theories" I am assuming that you mean "gauge theory" in the context of physics. In mathematics, the term "gauge theory" is a well-defined subfield of differential geometry: the study of connections on vector bundles, usually with special properties, and their associated moduli spaces. This is a huge area of current mathematical research. Some of it is physics inspired, but certainly not all of it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken "gauge field" in physics is equivalent to "connections on vector bundles" in maths. - In the context of your comment, I mean 'gauge theory' in the context of maths.

Comment: (ie. current pure mathematics inspired by / from "gauge (field) theory" in physics)

Comment: This question is awfully broad.  Are you looking for introductions to areas like Donaldson theory or Seiberg-Witten theory?

Answer (score 2):

See these

[Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820141)

[Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052163265X)

and, as a physicist, I would also add Faddeev and Slavnov

[Gauge Fields: An Introduction To Quantum Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201406349)

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Costello, [Renormalization and Effective Field Theory](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=surv-170)

Frédéric Paugam, [Towards the mathematics of quantum field theory](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~fpaugam/documents/enseignement/master-mathematical-physics.pdf)