# Reference request: Seminal papers in gauge-theoretic mathematics

Tags: gauge-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request

Following on from [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81881/reference-request-introductions-to-current-mathematics-related-to-gauge-theories)) I was also searching for seminal papers in gauge theory.

Would be greatly appreciative of references to such.

Comment: Sadiq- blanket requests for papers in a partIcular field are not an appropriate use of the site.

Comment: Maybe make the question into a CW. I don't have sufficient privilege for that though.

Answer (score 1):

[The Yang-Mills equations over Riemann surfaces](http://www.jstor.org/pss/37156) by M. F. Atiyah and R. Bott